# How do I find the quotient field of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Our teacher said sometimes the quotient field is $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{d}]$ and sometimes it's $\mathbb{Q}[\frac{1+\sqrt{d}}{2}]$. How do we decide, or what are the conditions on $d$ which helps us to decide, which is when?

Comment: Both of these fields are correct, they are the same. However, things are different when you regard the algebraic number rings.

Comment: It is also more standard to denote $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ instead of your notation; I think they result in the same ring in this case.

Comment: @Zardo different, how? Please explain some more?

Comment: You get a different number ring for $d \equiv 1 (4)$ (the second one) this can be seen by looking on the minimal polynomial of $a+b\sqrt{d}$ which is $(X-a)^2 -b^2m = X^2 -2aX + a^2-b^2m$.

Comment: @JackYoon The same ring when d is an algebraic number, is what you are saying?

Comment: @Zardo I don't understand the connection with the minimal polynomial here. If possible, can you please write in detail what you're saying in the answers. Also where can I find the proof, do you know?

Comment: do you know difference between $R[X]$ and $R(X)$ for a general ring $R$ and 'general' X?

And If $R$ is a field and $X$ is an agebraic number then those two should coincide but you would always write the latter version as it is a field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A number is called an algebraic integer if it is algebraic and the monic minimal polynomial has whole number coefficients. By looking at the minimal polynomial of a number $a+b\sqrt{d}$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$ which is $X^2 -2aX + a^2-b^2d$ you get, that $2a$ and $a^2-b^2d$ have to be whole numbers. Assuming $d$ is a squarefree integer, there is a (not so short, but simple) proof to get the number ring:

Looking at the minimal polynomial coefficents, you get that either both $a$ and $b$ are whole numbers, or $2a=k$ is an odd number and $a^2-b^2d \in \mathbb{Z}$ which is equivalent (by multiplying by $4$) to $k^2 \equiv 4b^2d \mod 4$. ($b$ is not necessarily in $\mathbb{Z}$ but $4b^2d$ is!) Since $k$ is odd, $k^2 \equiv 1 \mod 4$, so you get $4b^2d \equiv 1 \mod 4$. Writing $b=\frac p q$ ($p$, $q$ coprime) and using the definition of congruence, you get $\exists n \in \mathbb{Z}: (4n-1)q^2 = 4p^2d$. Since $d$ is assumed squarefree, $q^2$ and $d$ are coprime, so $q^2$ and $p^2d$ are coprime and we get $q^2 \vert 4$, so $q=1,2$. $q=1$ leads to a contradiction mod $4$, so $q=2$ and $p$ must be odd. We get $\exists n \in \mathbb{Z}: (4n-1) = p^2d$. Since $p$ is odd $p^2 \equiv 1 \mod 4$ so reducing modulo $4$ gives $d \equiv -1 \mod 4$.

This shows the implication: $\frac{1+\sqrt d} 2$ algebraic integer, then $d \equiv -1 \mod 4$. (a rather ugly proof, if you ask me...) The inverse statement is a little easier to prove, just plug in $a=b= \frac 1 2$. Working out the rings of integers from this is easy now.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Is "$2a=k$ is an odd number" a typo?

Comment: No, it isn't, $a$ does not have to be a whole  number, but $2a$ has to be. This number may be odd.